# Runs on localhost:4000 but not on Github blog

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

1. Minimal Mistakes Jekylltheme in use
2. Go to the _sass/_navigation.scss folder and apply the font effect directly to that tag
3. Localhost:4000 is reflected as changed, but not in the GitHub blog.

1. How to change the site title and category style respectively and reflect it on the GitHub blog
2. How to reflect jemoji on GitHub blog
(I've tried to copy how to google it, but it doesn't work)

localhost page

[image: 1]

github blog

[image: 2]